# Can I import all things in one file and then export it from there?

Tags: import

I know that we can indeed do this, Import everything ever needed in one file and then export it from there like:

```
import {Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import {fetchUserData} from './Stores/Server_Store_'
import HomePage from './Pages_Common/page-Homepage'
import AdminNav from './Pages_Admin/Nav-AdminNavbar'

export {Routes,Route, fetchUserData,HomePage, AdminNav}
```

And then import wherever these things needed from this "All-imports" file rather than their individual location, So now instead of importing like this:

```
import {Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import {fetchUserData} from './Stores/Server_Store_'
import HomePage from './Pages_Common/page-Homepage'
import AdminNav from './Pages_Admin/Nav-AdminNavbar'
```

We can simply do this:

```
import {AdminNav,HomePage,Route,Routes,fetchUserData} from './All-Imports'
```

But my question is: "Is this approach viable in the long run?" If not, please suggest me a better approach where I can minimize the space taken by these imports as it creates a mess on top of the actual code (I don't want to collapse them using the Code editor like VS-code as its just a visual play and do not actually minimizes the space taken by the imports)